# Unable to get k3s server running on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: k3s

I installed K3S on Ubuntu 18.04 as below:

```
curl -LO "https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/$(curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl"
chmod +x ./kubectl
sudo mv ./kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl
kubectl version --client
curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | sh -
sudo kubectl get nodes
```

However, when I do `sudo kubectl get nodes`, I get error below

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-62:~$ sudo kubectl get nodes
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

I checked the running processes for three important ports

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-62:~$ sudo lsof -i:6443
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
k3s-serve 2295 root   15u  IPv6  28164      0t0  TCP *:6443 (LISTEN)
k3s-serve 2295 root  166u  IPv6  31995      0t0  TCP ip-10-0-0-62.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:6443->ip-10-42-0-2.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:45338 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  168u  IPv4  30182      0t0  TCP localhost:59284->localhost:6443 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  173u  IPv4  27307      0t0  TCP localhost:59176->localhost:6443 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  177u  IPv6  28302      0t0  TCP localhost:6443->localhost:59176 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  182u  IPv6  27361      0t0  TCP localhost:6443->localhost:59226 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  184u  IPv4  28411      0t0  TCP localhost:59226->localhost:6443 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  185u  IPv4  27363      0t0  TCP ip-10-0-0-62.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:47226->ip-10-0-0-62.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:6443 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  186u  IPv6  27364      0t0  TCP ip-10-0-0-62.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:6443->ip-10-0-0-62.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:47226 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  188u  IPv4  27368      0t0  TCP localhost:59230->localhost:6443 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  190u  IPv6  28414      0t0  TCP localhost:6443->localhost:59230 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  194u  IPv4  28418      0t0  TCP localhost:59232->localhost:6443 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  195u  IPv4  28419      0t0  TCP localhost:59234->localhost:6443 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  196u  IPv4  28420      0t0  TCP localhost:59236->localhost:6443 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  197u  IPv6  27405      0t0  TCP localhost:6443->localhost:59232 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  198u  IPv6  27406      0t0  TCP localhost:6443->localhost:59234 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  199u  IPv6  27407      0t0  TCP localhost:6443->localhost:59236 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  204u  IPv4  27411      0t0  TCP localhost:59238->localhost:6443 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  205u  IPv6  32305      0t0  TCP ip-10-0-0-62.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:6443->ip-10-42-0-4.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:49256 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  209u  IPv4  28426      0t0  TCP localhost:59240->localhost:6443 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  210u  IPv4  27420      0t0  TCP localhost:59242->localhost:6443 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  211u  IPv6  34769      0t0  TCP ip-10-0-0-62.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:6443->ip-10-42-0-6.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:56858 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  212u  IPv4  28428      0t0  TCP localhost:59246->localhost:6443 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  213u  IPv6  28429      0t0  TCP localhost:6443->localhost:59238 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  214u  IPv6  28430      0t0  TCP localhost:6443->localhost:59240 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  215u  IPv6  28431      0t0  TCP localhost:6443->localhost:59242 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  216u  IPv6  34771      0t0  TCP ip-10-0-0-62.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:6443->ip-10-42-0-6.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:56860 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  217u  IPv6  28433      0t0  TCP localhost:6443->localhost:59246 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  218u  IPv4  27438      0t0  TCP localhost:59248->localhost:6443 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  220u  IPv6  28449      0t0  TCP localhost:6443->localhost:59248 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  221u  IPv6  28450      0t0  TCP localhost:6443->localhost:59250 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  225u  IPv4  28442      0t0  TCP localhost:59250->localhost:6443 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  240u  IPv4  28731      0t0  TCP localhost:59254->localhost:6443 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  241u  IPv4  28732      0t0  TCP localhost:59256->localhost:6443 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  242u  IPv6  28733      0t0  TCP localhost:6443->localhost:59254 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  243u  IPv6  28734      0t0  TCP localhost:6443->localhost:59256 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  250u  IPv4  29978      0t0  TCP localhost:59264->localhost:6443 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  252u  IPv6  29980      0t0  TCP localhost:6443->localhost:59264 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  253u  IPv4  29232      0t0  TCP localhost:59266->localhost:6443 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  254u  IPv4  29233      0t0  TCP localhost:59268->localhost:6443 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  255u  IPv6  29234      0t0  TCP localhost:6443->localhost:59266 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  256u  IPv6  29982      0t0  TCP localhost:6443->localhost:59268 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  257u  IPv4  29286      0t0  TCP localhost:59270->localhost:6443 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  258u  IPv6  29287      0t0  TCP localhost:6443->localhost:59270 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  259u  IPv6  34773      0t0  TCP ip-10-0-0-62.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:6443->ip-10-42-0-6.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:56862 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  260u  IPv6  30184      0t0  TCP localhost:6443->localhost:59284 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  261u  IPv6  36154      0t0  TCP ip-10-0-0-62.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:6443->ip-10-42-0-6.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:56864 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  262u  IPv6  31996      0t0  TCP ip-10-0-0-62.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:6443->ip-10-42-0-2.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:45340 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  263u  IPv6  31998      0t0  TCP ip-10-0-0-62.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:6443->ip-10-42-0-2.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:45342 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  264u  IPv6  32076      0t0  TCP ip-10-0-0-62.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:6443->ip-10-42-0-3.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:35926 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  265u  IPv6  31674      0t0  TCP ip-10-0-0-62.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:6443->ip-10-42-0-3.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:35928 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  266u  IPv6  32122      0t0  TCP ip-10-0-0-62.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:6443->ip-10-42-0-3.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:35936 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  267u  IPv6  31675      0t0  TCP ip-10-0-0-62.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:6443->ip-10-42-0-3.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:35930 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  268u  IPv6  31676      0t0  TCP ip-10-0-0-62.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:6443->ip-10-42-0-3.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:35932 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  269u  IPv6  31677      0t0  TCP ip-10-0-0-62.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:6443->ip-10-42-0-3.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:35934 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  270u  IPv6  31705      0t0  TCP ip-10-0-0-62.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:6443->ip-10-42-0-3.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:35938 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  271u  IPv6  33226      0t0  TCP ip-10-0-0-62.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:6443->ip-10-42-0-4.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:49258 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  272u  IPv6  33229      0t0  TCP ip-10-0-0-62.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:6443->ip-10-42-0-4.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:49260 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  273u  IPv4  32308      0t0  TCP localhost:59490->localhost:6443 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  274u  IPv6  32309      0t0  TCP localhost:6443->localhost:59490 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  275u  IPv4  33234      0t0  TCP localhost:59492->localhost:6443 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  276u  IPv6  32311      0t0  TCP localhost:6443->localhost:59492 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  277u  IPv4  33645      0t0  TCP localhost:59586->localhost:6443 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  279u  IPv6  33646      0t0  TCP localhost:6443->localhost:59586 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  283u  IPv4  33650      0t0  TCP localhost:59592->localhost:6443 (ESTABLISHED)
k3s-serve 2295 root  286u  IPv6  32741      0t0  TCP localhost:6443->localhost:59592 (ESTABLISHED)
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-62:~$ sudo lsof -i:8472
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-62:~$ sudo lsof -i:10250
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
k3s-serve 2295 root  224u  IPv6  28440      0t0  TCP *:10250 (LISTEN)
k3s-serve 2295 root  226u  IPv6  37502      0t0  TCP ip-10-0-0-62.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:10250->ip-10-42-0-4.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:47148 (ESTABLISHED)
```

Not sure what is the issue and how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to check your `.kube/config`. Your error message indicates kubectl tries to connect to `localhost:8080` but your `lsof` call indicates you expect communication to happen on port 6443. Check in particular the `clusters` section in your kubectl configuration. It may be the wrong active context or wrong server URL.